# How do I pass custom props to dynamic components in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, components, vuejs3

I have an array containing data of questions that will be displayed. Only one question must be displayed at a time. Once the user selects an answer to a question, they can move to the next one by the click of a button.

I have a component called `QuestionCard` that displays the questions and the answer options. Here's the code of `QuestionCard.vue`:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
   props: {
      name: String,
      question: String,
      answer_options: Array,
   }
});
</script>


<template>
   <div>
      <h4>{{ question }}</h4>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li v-for="(option, index) in answer_options" :key="index">
               <button>{{  String.fromCharCode(65 + index) + ') ' + option }}</button>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

The array containing the question data is inside the `App.vue` file. I have simplified the questions and reduced the count, but in actuality there will be a number of questions which will be fetched from the back end server.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import QuestionCard from "./components/QuestionCard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
   components: {
      QuestionCard
   },
   data() {
      return {
         questionArray: [
            {
               id: "123",
               question: "Which of these is a colour in the rainbow?",
               options: [
                  'red', 'black', 'brown'
               ],
            }, {
               id: "456",
               question: "How many continents does Earth have?",
               options: [
                  1, 7, 6, 9
               ],
            }, {
               id: "789",
               question: "Which of these is a prime number?",
               options: [
                  7, 4, 44, 35
               ],
            },
         ],

         currentComponent: 
      }
   },
})
</script>


<template>
   <div>
      <div id="top_bar">
         <button>Next Question</button>
      </div>

      <div id="question_section">
         <component :is="currentComponent"></component>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

In this scenario, there will be 3 `QuestionCard`s and the value of the props of each of them will be different. How do I use Vue's dynamic components to achieve display one `QuestionCard` at a time?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**:

App.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import QuestionCard from "./components/QuestionCard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
   components: {
      QuestionCard
   },
   data() {
      return {
         questionArray: [
            {
               id: "123",
               question: "Which of these is a colour in the rainbow?",
               options: [
                  'red', 'black', 'brown'
               ],
            },
            {
               id: "456",
               question: "How many continents does Earth have?",
               options: [
                  1, 7, 6, 9
               ],
            },
            {
               id: "789",
               question: "Which of these is a prime number?",
               options: [
                  7, 4, 44, 35
               ],
            },
         ],
         currentQuestionIndex: 0
   },
   methods: {
      nextQuestion() {
         if (this.currentQuestionIndex < this.questionArray.length - 1) {
            this.currentQuestionIndex++;
         }
      }
   }
})
</script>

<template>
   <div>
      <div id="top_bar">
         <button @click="nextQuestion">Next Question</button>
      </div>

      <div id="question_section">
         <QuestionCard 
            :question="questionArray[currentQuestionIndex].question"
            :answer_options="questionArray[currentQuestionIndex].options"
         ></QuestionCard>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This works fine. I don't quite understand - why isn't usage dynamic components necessary here? I think, I haven't properly understood it's use case.